# Compressible Poiseuille Flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Poiseuille's_equation_for_compressible_fluids) (without providing a reference) gives a formula for the mass flow rate in compressible Poiseuille flow. Does anybody know where this formula comes from? Are there exact solutions of the Navier-Stokes equation for compressible Poiseuille flow?

Comment: The assumptions used in deriving the formula are clearly stated in the preceding paragraph.

Comment: @ChesterMiller  I see the assumptions (ideal gas eos, isothermal flow), but the formula is not an obvious consequence of these assumptions, and there is no reference (the rest of the wiki page is standard text book material, and properly referenced).

Comment: It's a really crude approximation.  The pressure is assumed to vary linearly with position from entrance to exit.  The average volumetric is first calculated, based on the Hagen Poiseuille.  Then the volumetric flow rate is corrected by multiplying by the ratio of the average pressure to the exit pressure to get the volumetric flow rate at the exit.

Comment: Thanks, but I fail to understand why this $(P_i-P_o)/(2P_o)$ is the right correction factor. The wiki page also seems to imply that the formula is the result of an actual calculation, which can be interpreted as "Hagen-Poisseuille" $\times$ "correction factor".

Comment: For steady isothermal flow, the density is proportional to the pressure, and the mean velocity of flow is thus inversely proportional to the pressure.  Try applying that condition locally with hagen-poiseulle  and see where it leads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hagen-Poiseulle locally:  $$-\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{128Q\eta}{\pi D^4}$$
Multiply both sides by p:

$$-\frac{dp^2}{dx}=\frac{256(Qp)\eta}{\pi D^4}$$
But, for constant temperature, continuity requires that $Qp=Q_1p_1=Q_2p_2$  Therefore, integrating both sides gives:
$$p_1^2-p_2^2=\frac{256L\eta}{\pi D^4}(Q_2p_2)$$So, mathematically, $$Q_2=\frac{(p_1-p_2)\pi D^4}{128L}\frac{(p_1+p_2)}{2p_2}$$

Comment: Thanks. By the way: We also seem to assume that the kinematic viscosity (here called $\eta=\mu/\rho$) is independent of $\rho$.

Comment: Not in my judgment,